# Computation of the likelihood of a sample

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Let $U_1 \dots U_n $ be i.i.d sample from an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Let $$Y_i =\min{(U_i,c)}$$ where $c$ is a known constant. 
>   Find the likelihood for $\lambda$.

To do this I tried to find the distribution of $Y_i$, and I did it as follows: 
$$P(Y_i \ge y )= \begin{cases} 1,& {\rm{if }}\; y \leq c & \\  1-e ^{-\lambda y }, &{\rm{if }}\; y > c  \end{cases} $$ 
Then I tried to compute the density of $Y_i$, but I'm not sure it is correct, I found that it is: 
$$\frac{1}{c}\mathbf{1}_{\{y \leq c\} } (y) + \lambda e^{-\lambda y }  \mathbf{1}_{\{y > c \}} $$ 
Is it correct ? 
And how can I go on with this ?

Comment: $Y\leq c$ so when does the second case hold?

Comment: The likelihood of $\lambda$ is just the joint density of the $U_i$'s viewed as a function of $\lambda$, and in this case using the independence it would be $$\lambda^n \exp\left(-\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n U_i\right)$$... is this not what's being asked? The $Y_i$ seems irrelevant. Are you asked to compute the likelihood of $\lambda$ given that you only get to observe the $Y_i$'s?

Answer (score 1):

It might help to be slightly more careful. Let's compute the min as $$\min(U_i,c) =c\mathbb{1}_{\{U_i\geq c\}} + U_i \mathbb{1}_{\{U_i < c\}} $$
Thus $Y_i = c$ with probability $e^{-\lambda c}$ and $Y_i = U_i$ with probability $1-e^{-\lambda c}$. Now we can ask what $F(y)= P(Y_i\leq y)$ is. If $y\geq c$ then clearly $F(y)=1$, but if $y < c$ we can compute by partitioning based on  $U_i$
$$F(y) = P(Y_i < y, U_i \leq c) + P(Y_i < y, U_i > c) = P(U_i \leq y) + P(\emptyset)=1-e^{-\lambda y}$$ So the distribution of $Y_i$ is $$F(y) = \begin{cases} 1, &y\geq c\\ 1-e^{-\lambda y}, &0<y< c  \end{cases}$$
and since the distribution jumps at $y=c$ there is no density (there is one in the measure-theoretic sense but we won't go there), but the "likelihood" of an observation can still be thought of as $$L_i(\lambda|y) = \begin{cases} \lambda e^{-\lambda y}, & 0< y < c\\ e^{-\lambda c}, & y=c\\ 0, &y >c \end{cases} $$
now use independence and take the product to get
$$ L(\lambda|y_1,\ldots,y_n) = \prod_i L_i(\lambda,y_i)$$
which will of course depend on where the $y_i$'s land with respect to the conditions on $L_i$.